# change the html content after getting it from a url with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am using javascript code to get html content from one the pages, while at the same time i also want to change the content i get from html (inside the carttitle id). how can i change the value of id=carttitle on the cartbox.html below dynamically?

this is the code (div where the html will be located)

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!-- button to trigger the function -->
<button onclick="getcontent('cartbox.html','#cartboxes','#cartbox');">getcontent</button> <!-- the cartbox.html will fill the content below -->
<ul class="cartboxes" id="cartboxes">

</ul>
```

this is the javascript code function to get the html

```js
// select.js
function getcontent(url, from, to) {
  var cached = sessionStorage[url];
  if (!from) {
    from = "body";
  } // default to grabbing body tag
  if (to && to.split) {
    to = document.querySelector(to);
  } // a string TO turns into an element
  if (!to) {
    to = document.querySelector(from);
  } // default re-using the source elm as the target elm
  if (cached) {
    return to.innerHTML = cached;
  } // cache responses for instant re-use re-use

  var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest; // new ajax
  XHRt.responseType = 'document'; // ajax2 context and onload() event
  XHRt.onload = function() {
    sessionStorage[url] = to.innerHTML = XHRt.response.querySelector(from).innerHTML;
  };
  XHRt.open("GET", url, true);
  XHRt.send();
  return XHRt;
}
```

this is the html code that i will get the content from

```html
<!-- cartbox.html -->
<div id="cartbox">
  <li>
    <div class="cartbox">
      <div class="cartboxleft">
        <img src="img/search.png" width="60px" height="60px">
      </div>
      <div class="cartboxright">
        <!-- i want to change the value of the carttitle below dynamically -->
        <b class="carttitle" id="carttitle">nice Pizza</b>
        <p class="cartdescription">Number: <b>1</b></p>
        <p class="cartdescription">Price: <b>$ 11.22</b></p>
      </div>
      <div class="cartboxdelete">
        <button class="deletebutton" onclick="deleteitem(this);">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the text "nice Pizza" ?

Comment: yes, i want to change the content dynamically from the javascript

Comment: So what prevents you from using getElementById and changing the text?

Comment: where should i put the getElementById ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `responseType  = 'text'` as `document` responseType is not recommended to avoids wasting time parsing HTML uselessly. Now regarding your issue, you can do like this:

```js
function getcontent(url, fromSelector, toSelector) {
    var cached = sessionStorage[url];
    if (cached) {
        return toSelector.innerHTML = cached;
    }

    fromSelector = fromSelector || 'body';
    toSelector = toSelector && document.querySelector(toSelector) || document.querySelector(fromSelector);

    var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest();
    XHRt.open("GET", url, true);

    XHRt.responseType = 'text';
    XHRt.onload = function() {
        if (XHRt.readyState === XHRt.DONE && XHRt.status === 200) {
            toSelector.innerHTML = XHRt.responseText;
            document.getElementById('carttitle').innerHTML = 'your new value';
            sessionStorage[url] = toSelector.innerHTML; // Now it will work after loading from session storage.
        }
    };

    XHRt.send();
}
```

Comment: this is great answer, just one thing when i trigger the function at first the carttitle value change but then it return back to nice pizza afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Your cache process will not work because you are selecting a property with the brackets operator `[]` on the session storage object.
Instead use the [`getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) method to get the key that you are looking for.

```
var cached = sessionStorage.getItem(url);
```

In your second `if` statement you check `to` and `to.split`. Unless the `to` string has a `split` property, this will fail. Your intentions here seem unknown. Instead just check for the string to be a valid string instead.

```
if (to && 'string' === typeof to) {
```

The part where you create a new instance of `XMLHttpRequest` will fail because you are missing the parenthesis to call the constructor.

```
var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Then in your `onload` callback you have to save the `innerHTML` of your result in the session storage using the [`setItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method.

But before doing that, select the cart title element with `querySelector` and change the content of the element if you need it to.

```
XHRt.onload = function() {
  let element = this.response.querySelector(from);
  if (element !== null) {
    let cartTitle = element.querySelector('#carttitle');
    cartTitle.textContent = 'An even better pizza';
    let html = element.innerHTML;
    to.innerHTML = html;
    sessionStorage.setItem(url, html);
  }
};
```